# How to add properties in the end of the two first lines with double quote

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

We want to add the following properties:

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M
```

in the two first lines that contain the word - **HBASE_MASTER_OPTS**

*Example before change*

```
more ams-hbase-env-template.txt


export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=71 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=72 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=73 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
```

*Example after change ( expected results )*

```
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=71 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=72 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=73 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
```

What I did until now is that

```
sed -i '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/ s/$/-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

But this isnt right becauae

1. we want the properties before the end of double quote
2. properties must be only on the first two lines that variable is HBASE_MASTER_OPTS
3. **in case properties already in line, then it will not append again on any next time!**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is - How to add properties in the end of the two first lines with double quote , as I explained in the expected results

Comment: It looks like you've given a list of requirements rather than a question.

Comment: yes the requirements 1-3 are because my solution isn't good enough , so I just mentions what should be

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it appears that you've just copied and pasted some code from somewhere without understanding what it does or making any attempt to modify it to do what you need to do.

Comment: not exactly , I just start with that , but I am stuck with the remarks that I mentioned , I can continue to find solution but I need advice

Comment: Are there really blank lines like that in the file?

Comment: if you mean about the empty lines , then its only example , you can ignore the empty lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/{x;s/^/x/;/^x\{1,2\}$/{x;/-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/b;s/"\s*$/ -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"/;x};x}' file
```

On a line containing `HBASE_MASTER_OPTS` increment a counter in the hold space and if that counter contains 1 or 2, and does not contain the string `-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M` then replace the last `"` with `-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"`, otherwise do nothing to the line.

Comment: very nice , I will test it on my Linux machine soon , btw what you think about my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&/ -XX:\+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/{x++;print;next}/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&x<2{gsub(/"$/," -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M\"");x++}1' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

test:

```
 awk '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&/ -XX:\+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/{x++;print;next}/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&x<2{gsub(/"$/," -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M\"");x++}1' example.txt



export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"

export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=71 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"

export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=72 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"

export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=73 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
```

Comment: *＋1* for keeping the site tidy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will give you some inspiration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 0;

while (<>) {
    if ($i < 2 && /HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/ && !/UseGCLogFileRotation/) {
        s/"$/ -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"/;
        $i++;
    }

    print;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ perl a.pl foo.txt
```

Comment: can we use your script as perl line liner so I will able to insert it to my bash script?

Comment: Sure. Any Perl program could theoretically be written as a one-liner.

Comment: ok , I will try to convert it to one line , I will update , if it success

Comment: any way I answered also to my question , so if my answer is good for you , then you can up vote my answer -:)